# How to persist Object in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, mongodb, concurrency

I need to implement a following architecture:

N threads are monitoring `BlockedQueue<Message>` (I can even consider that we can use ActiveMQ in near future).

When message captured I perform few modification on this message and I need to persist it in MongoDB database.

The service is something like this:

```
@Repository(value="service")
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate; 

public void save(Message message){
  //do something to message
  doSomething(message);
  //persist it
  mongoTemplate.save(message, "messages");
}
//etc...
}
```

Now I need to share `Service` object between threads.

How can I make this service Thread-Safe? Will it be good practice to make Service object as singleton (Design Pattern) and inject it to Runnabble beans using `getInstance()` method factory?

Should my mongoDb template have N connections opened(kind of connection pool)?

May be there are some other ways to share such service between threads?

Comment: First, I personally don't think that `Service` is a good name for a class.

Can you just make `save` method `synchronized`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB driver handles connection pool already and it is thread-safe as well if you don't modify `Message` object during the call. Therefore, if `doSomething(message)` is thread-safe, your service code should be okay.

Note: mongoTemplate.save(message, "messages") seems to have incorrect argument order. You should pass collection name first.

Comment: Should I implement factory method getInstance() or should inject it as regular Spring singleton?